# When does a readied action trigger on "when the enemy moves"?

Tags: dnd-5e, readied-action

Follow up from [Can I specify the timing "before ..." for my ready action?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/120771/can-i-specify-the-timing-before-for-my-ready-action)

When my trigger is "when the enemy moves", **when does the readied action trigger,** after they move 5 ft, or after finished moving to their intended location?

I'm asking because I might want to use a pike to deliver the spell. If it triggers after the target move 5 ft, then I can still attack them and complete the spell. If it waits until the target completes their movement, then they might have leave the 10 ft reach of pike, and thus waste my spell.

Comment: BTW, what allows you to deliver a spell through a weapon?

Comment: Oh, the Booming Blade cantrip.

Comment: That has a range of 5 ft, so you cannot benefit from reach weapons.

Comment: @Szega When I ready (and cast) the spell, the enemy is within 5 ft of me, so they are a valid target for the Booming Blade, right?

Comment: They also need to *stay* a valid target for it go off.

Comment: @Szega If the enemy moves alongside the PC (i.e. move 5ft without increasing distance from the PC) or the two characters start the turn engaged, this case still comes up.

Comment: @gul I did not say that this cannot work ever, with any kind of movement. I was just clarifying something for Vylix based on his last paragraph.

Comment: @Szega Well, so, I was intending to respond to the "you cannot benefit from the reach weapons" statement, but it might be arising from me misunderstanding Booming Blade. I'll go post that as a question elsewhere.