# Can you react mid movement?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, reactions

Alice and Belle are in combat, 30ft apart from each other.

Alice takes first turn, and readies an action; "If Belle comes within 25ft of me, I move my full speed directly away."

On Belle's turn, Belle says "I move 30ft right next to Alice."

[Ready](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#Ready) states: "When the trigger occurs, you can either take your reaction right after the trigger finishes or ignore the trigger." Does this mean that Belle is able to move next to Alice before Alice is able to react?

[Breaking Up Your Move](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#BreakingUpYourMove) states: "You can break up your movement on your turn, using some of your speed before and after your action." Does this mean that even if Belle moves in 5ft increments towards Alice, it is still one "move" and so Alice still cannot react before Belle is right next to them?

Comment: Yeap, the first item in [When does a reaction happen if the trigger is movement?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/118861/when-does-a-reaction-happen-if-the-trigger-is-movement) is essentially the same question, and the answer from Rubik already answers this one as well.